# How do we mock fetch for Redux Async Actions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, redux, nock

In the [Writing Tests](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) section of Redux, how does the `store.dispatch(actions.fetchTodos())` not invoke the `fetch` method, if `store.dispatch` is literally calling `actions.fetchTodos`?

```
it('creates FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS when fetching todos has been done', (done) => {
    nock('http://example.com/')
      .get('/todos')
      .reply(200, { todos: ['do something'] })

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: types.FETCH_TODOS_REQUEST },
      { type: types.FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS, body: { todos: ['do something']  } }
    ]
    const store = mockStore({ todos: [] }, expectedActions, done)
    store.dispatch(actions.fetchTodos())
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is calling the `fetch` method, but the `nock` line:

```
nock('http://example.com/')
  .get('/todos')
  .reply(200, { todos: ['do something'] })
```

stubs out the HTTP request so that `fetch` simply returns the right data (without actually hitting the endpoint).

Another option is to extract the call to `fetch` into another module — say, `api` — and use it inside your action creator. In tests, you would simply mock out the appropriate methods on the `api` module.

Comment: So if my fetch is in another module, then I would I just mock(spy?) actions.fetchTodos()? (since actions.fetchTodos currently has fetch in it.) Then would there be no need for nock?

Comment: @Tai If you moved the call to `fetch` into something like `api.fetchTodos`, and then your action creator called `api.fetchTodos`, then you would simply mock/spy `api.fetchTodos` and `fetch` would never be called. The version in the Redux docs is probably a better test, since it's actually testing that the correct URL is being called, etc.

Comment: Thank you. That helped clarify the whole issue I was having. I think it was just a misunderstanding of the scope of a unit test.

Comment: Is it possible to mock api.fetchTodos while dispatching actions.fetchTodos() in the same test file, or is that a seperate test entirely?

Comment: @Tai Sure, why not? (Perhaps I'm missing something.) In this case, you would stub out `api.fetchTodos` specifically because you're trying to test `actions.fetchTodos`